# LAPACKE C++ complex Matrix Inversion

Tags: c++, lapack, matrix-inverse, lapacke

Im trying to invert a complex matrix in C++ using the LAPACKE package. My code is as follows:

```
void inv(std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>> &ans, std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>> MAT){
    int N = MAT.size();
    int *IPIV = new int[N];
    std::complex<double> ** arr = new std::complex<double>*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        arr[i] = new std::complex<double>[N];
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){
            arr[i][j] = MAT[i][j];
        }
    }

    LAPACKE_cgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, arr[0], N, IPIV); 
    LAPACKE_cgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, arr[0], N, IPIV);
    for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){                                                                                                                                                      
            ans[i][j] = arr[i][j];                                                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    delete IPIV;                                                                                                                                                                
    delete arr;                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

which gives an error:

```
utils.cc:253:59: error: cannot convert 'std::complex<double>*' to '__complex__ 
float*' for argument '4' to 'int LAPACKE_cgetrf(int, int, int, __complex__ float*, 
int, int* '                                                                                                                                                                                
LAPACKE_cgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, arr[0], N, IPIV);                                                                                                                                                                          ^                                                                                                                
utils.cc:254:56: error: cannot convert 'std::complex<double>*' to '__complex__ 
float*' for argument '3' to 'int LAPACKE_cgetri(int, int, __complex__ float*, int, 
const int*)'                                                                                                                                                                               
LAPACKE_cgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, arr[0], N, IPIV);
```

I tried doing:

```
__complex__ float ** arr = new __complex__ float *[N];                                                                                                                      
for (int i = 0; i<N; i++){                                                                                                                                                      
    arr[i] = new __complex__ float [N];                                                                                                                                         
    for (int j = 0; j<N; j++){                                                                                                                                                      
        arr[i][j] = reinterpret_cast<float(&)[2]>(MAT[i][j]);                                                                                                                   
    }                                                                                                                                                                       
}
```

for the first loop in the function, but it gives:

```
 error: cannot convert 'float [2]' to '__complex__ float' in assignment                                                                                                  
 arr[i][j] = reinterpret_cast<float(&)[2]>(MAT[i][j]);
```

what am I doing wrong? I have another inv function that works fine with doubles. It's the complex types I'm having trouble with.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! `LAPACKE_cgetrf()` wraps Lapack `cgetrf()` that handles complex simple precision float. [`LAPACKE_zgetrf()`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d56/lapacke__zgetrf_8c_a9ec730a8654106933ca22548c93afdcd.html), intented for double precision float, will likely help you. Take a quick look at LAPACK [naming scheme](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node24.html). Depending on the structure or your matrix, you may even get a "better" inversion method than that intended for general matrices `ge`. And the matrix need be flattened as a contiguous array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LAPACK might expect continuous data block. ALong the lines

```
void inv(std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>> &ans, std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>> MAT){
    using cfloat = __complex__ float;
    int N = MAT.size();

    cfloat* arr = new cfloat [N*N];
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i) {            
        for (int j = 0; j != N; ++j){
            int idx = i*N + j;
            arr[idx] = (MAT[i][j]).real() + _Complex_I*(MAT[i][j]).imag();
        }
    }

    int* IPIV = new int[N];

    LAPACKE_cgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, arr, N, IPIV); 
    LAPACKE_cgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, arr, N, IPIV);
    for (int i = 0; i != N; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j != N; ++j){
            int idx = i*N + j;
            ans[i][j] = arr[idx];                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    delete [] IPIV;                                                                                                                                                                
    delete [] arr;                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Comment: @ImranAlkhatib Ok, I wrote how I think it should be, could you try it?

Comment: It says:  cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::complex<double> > >::value_type {aka std::complex<double>}' to 'cfloat {aka __complex__ float}' in assignment                                                                                                                                                         arr[idx] = MAT[i][j];

Comment: @ImranAlkhatib Ok, added initialization of C11 complex from C++ complex, could you try it?

Comment: It works! But only for the complex case. For the real case the inverse is wrong :| Thanks!

Comment: @ImranAlkhatib Good! Please accept the answer then. Wrt real case I would advise to ask another question with minimal reproducible example why you think it is not working